# selectize.js accumulates options from previous searches

Tags: javascript, selectize.js

I found that selectize accumulates options from previous searches.
I upload new list of options remotely from my server and the number of selected items not limited. In this case after several searches in dropdown I have a lot of options connected with old queries which I don't need.
How can I avoid this?
List of selectize options for initialize

```
 valueField: 'id'
 labelField: 'label_name'
 searchField: 'city_name'
 options: []
 create: false
 openOnFocus: false
```

Thx for any help.

Comment: Call clearOptions() before loading options from the server

Comment: @zooglash The problem, that clearOptions() remove all selected items in my input. Looks like clearOptions() call clear() inside.

Comment: Right, clearOptions() call clear()  https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/e080cf599e82628e3ceb3bc285b1096814585d84/dist/js/standalone/selectize.js#L2394

Comment: You're right. I would open an issue at github about this problem. Describe your use case and perhaps the developer will add a way to clear the existing options without removing the ones that the user selected.

Comment: As a workaround, you could clear the options selectively - go over the options and call removeOption only for those that aren't in the currently selected items. Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/smz8rxsp/

Comment: @zooglash, I posted my workaround. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is my solution](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/pull/1080) for this issue. Works good for me.